# After passing object to handlebars, how can I access that object in script tag?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I first get the data from sql then pass it into handlebars.

Inside the  tag in .handlebars/using view.js, I want to access doctors, but i keep getting[object][object]. I tried json.stringifying it before but still no luck. What is the best way to do this?

```js
umd.matchDocs(val2, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  var renderDocs = {
    doctors: data
  }
  res.render("dashboard", renderDocs);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> After passing object to handlebars, how can I access that object in script tag?

No, not by default.  But you can make the data available manually if you want.

Data you pass to handlebars rendering operation is available during the rendering operation only.  If you want to be able to access some of that data later in client-side `<script>` tags, then you can "render" Javascript variables into the `<script>` tags that contain the desired data.

Remember when rendering data into Javascript variables, you need to render the actual Javascript text (converting to JSON will often create the text for you).

In your specific example, you could do something like this in your rendering code:

```
umd.matchDocs(val2, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  var renderDocs = {
    doctors: JSON.stringify(data)
  }
  res.render("dashboard", renderDocs);
});
```

And, then in the template:

```
<script>
var doctors = {{{doctors}}};
</script>
```

Then, this array of doctors would be available to the Javascript in your page.

In case you haven't seen the triple braces like shown above, that's to tell handlebars to skip any HTML escaping in the data (because this isn't HTML).

Comment: I tried this and simply tried to console.log the data and it gives me [object][object].... any idea why? i even tried json.parse for the console.log

Comment: @user2763557 - Which `console.log()` are you talking about?  On server?  Or in web page?  And, are you using `doctors: JSON.stringify(data)` on the server before passing the data to handlebars?

Comment: console.log on the page. And yes using JSON.stringify(data) before passing the data

Comment: Then, add `console.log(renderDocs.doctors)` right before you call `res.render()` to see exactly what you're passing into the handlebars renderer.  And, show what your template code looks like.  YOU need to do some basic debugging to help diagnose things here.  Sorry, but we can't do that for you.

Comment: i did that! it console longs the data i get back from sql but can't figure out how i can parse this when i get it in handlebars: [ RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Dr.Gary Weinstein',
    specialty: 'G.P',
    location: 'Toronto',
    rating: 4,
    contactNumber: '4164859044',
    gender: 'M' },

Comment: I got it working! stupid spelling mistake, your answer was correct. Marking it correct now. thanks!